# wrap <tr> inside form for ajax file uploading

Tags: php

I am making a simple program for `editing/updating/inserting` in the table which contains table having columns of product names, price and image. The problem that I am facing is file uploading using `ajax`(how to use form data object sending data to PHP file using ajax). I tried to wrap  inside the form but not working (any alternative for this).

> dynamic PHP code

```
<form method="post" id="form'.$value['id'].'">
<tr class="jsgrid-filter-row" id="'.$value['id'].'">
<td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 163px"; id="lOcolumn'.$value['id'].'" >'.$value['productname'].'</td>
<td class="jsgrid-cell"  style="width: 100px"; id="accolumn'.$value['id'].'" >'.$value['price'].'</td>
<td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 100px"; id="cocolumn'.$value['id'].'" >'.$array[$value['productcategory']-1].'</td>
<td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-center" id="imagecolumn'.$value['id'].'" style="width: 100px;""><a target="_blank" href="./user/'.$value['imagelink'].'" id="image'.$value['id'].'">image '.$value['id'].'</td>
<td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-control-field jsgrid-align-center" style="width: 50px;" id="inputedit'.$value['id'].'"><input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-edit-button editButtonClass" id="editButtonn'.$value['id'].'" type="button" title="Edit"><input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-delete-button deleteButtonClass" type="button" title="Delete" id="deleteButton'.$value['id'].'"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: you cannot add a form tag in between table and tr tags. form tag should be outside of table tags.

Comment: Use js/jquery to fetch the relavent values and submit them by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){  
  evt.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this));
  $.ajax({
   url: 'fileUploadUrl',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   contentType: false,
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   processData: false,
   success: function (response) {
     alert(response);
   }
  });
 return false;
});
```

Please try above code. use jquery for file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Use js/jquery to fetch the relevant values and submit them by ajax. you cannot use form tag between table tags. see below example,

```js
$('.btn_save').click(function(){

let id = $(this).attr('data-id'); //this is the id of row

let name = $(this).parent().parent().find('.name').val(); //this is the name of relavent row
let price = $(this).parent().parent().find('.price').val(); //this is the price of relavent row

//do your ajax here

alert(id);
alert(name);
alert(price);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td><input class="name" type="text"></td>
  <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
  <td>
  <button data-id="1" class="btn_save">Save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="name" type="text"></td>
  <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
  <td>
  <button data-id="2" class="btn_save">Save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```